# AngularJS Directive called before Module.Config()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript1.4

I have a very particular scenario, and I can't identify the cause of it.

Brief overview of my situation:

I'm developing a small little application, as part of my learning TypeScript, and using AngularJS seemed to be a challenge almost everyone new to the TS system faces, so why not.

I have an app.ts file, that basically sets up required global variables and initializes the data-ng-app="" part required by AngularJS.

The app.ts file:

```
module Learning.AngularTS.Core
{
    "use strict";

    // ... environmental variables left out

    export var AngularTSApp: ng.IModule = angular.module("angularTSApp", []);
    export var ngCompileProvider: ng.ICompileProvider = null;

    AngularTSApp.config(function (
        $compileProvider: ng.ICompileProvider,
        $controllerProvider: ng.IControllerProvider): void
    {
        (<any>$controllerProvider).allowGlobals();
        ngCompileProvider = $compileProvider;
    });
}
```

Nothing special, a module just creates a 'namespaced' reference for me, and in here I export some variables, but the one of interest is the AngularTSApp variable, which needs it's configuration properties set.

In the .config() I'm attaching the reference to the Angular's CompileProvider to the variable ngCompileProvider, as per the code I posted.

The particular 'issue', I'm experiencing is when I'm trying to attach a Directive to the page, where the .config() only gets called after the directive, and I don't know why.

The directive:

```
module Learning.AngularTS.Directives
{
    "use strict";

    Learning.AngularTS.Core.ngCompileProvider.directive.apply(null,
        ["MyTestDirective",
            ["$parse", "$compile",
                function ($parse: ng.IParseService,
                    $compile: ng.ICompileService): ng.IDirective
                {
                    return <ng.IDirective>{
                        restrict: "E",
                        replace: false,
                        transclude: true,
                        templateUrl: "",
                        scope: {
                            value: "=",
                            edit: "@"
                        },
                        link: function ($scope: any, $rootElement: ng.IRootElementService, $attributes: ng.IAttributes): any
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }]]);
}
```

On face value, this looks fine, when the JS file loads, `Learning.AngularTS.Core.ngCompileProvider` is null, because it has not been initialized as per the .config() section in app.ts.

Is there something wrong with my approach, and if so, is there a better way to do this?